# Rearanging numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I need to parse the time-dependent positions of two objects and I get data in numpy array:

```
data = [[0, 1, 2],
        [1, 4, 3],
        [2, 2, 1]]
```

so that the first column represents a *position*, the second one the time point A was in that particular position and the last column time at which point B was in that position. It is guaranteed that data is consistent, that is if any two rows have the same times - they have the same position, in pseudocode:

```
data[row1,1] == data[row2,1]  <=>  data[row1,0] == data[row2,0]
data[row1,2] == data[row2,2]  <=>  data[row1,0] == data[row2,0]
```

What I would love to have is to somehow recast this array so it would enumerate all available *times* and according positions, such as:

```
parsed = [[1, 0, 2],
          [2, 2, 0],
          [3, np.nan, 1],
          [4, 1, np.nan]]
```

Here, first column is the time, second is position of point A and third one is position of point B. np.nan should be assigned when I do not have the information on position of a point. What I currently do is rip the data array into two separate arrays:

```
    moments = set (data [:, 1:3].flatten())

    for each in moments:
        a = data[:,[1,0]][pos[:,1] == each]
        b = data[:,[2,0]][pos[:,2] == each]
```

and the I re-merge the as done in [John Galt's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510806/merge-numpy-arrays-based-on-date). This works somehow, but I am really hoping there may be something of a better solution.  Can anyone kick me in the right direction?

Comment: Just a comment for the future reference; I made a clumsy statement in the question. When I write " It is guaranteed that data is consistent, that is if any two rows have the same times - they have the same position" this is true, but of course vice versa is NOT, as suggested in the "pseudocode" when using the symbol "<==>"  - it is perfectly ok for a point to have the same position and different times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach using NumPy array initialization and assignment -

```
# Gather a and b indices. Get their union, that represents all posssible indices
a_idx = data[:,1]
b_idx = data[:,2]
all_idx = np.union1d(a_idx, b_idx)

# Setup o/p array 
out = np.full((all_idx.size,3),np.nan)

# Assign all indices to first col
out[:,0] = all_idx

# Determine the positions of a indices in all indices and assign first col data
out[np.searchsorted(all_idx, a_idx),1] = data[:,0]
# Similarly for b
out[np.searchsorted(all_idx, b_idx),2] = data[:,0]
```

[`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) acts like a godsend here, as it gives us the locations where we need to put in `a` and `b` from `data` in the already sorted array `all_idx` and is known to be quite efficient.

Output for given sample data -

```
In [104]: out
Out[104]: 
array([[  1.,   0.,   2.],
       [  2.,   2.,   0.],
       [  3.,  nan,   1.],
       [  4.,   1.,  nan]])
```

Comment: Sweet lord, this thing flys! So, you use union1d instead that thing I did with set(). You initialize corresponding final array with nans, and use searchsorted () to copy to the place according to vector of moments, for the lack of better word? I am upvoting this and if test data come out ok, I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: @StipeGalić ... according to the order of all possible indices, which happens to be sorted and that lets us leverage the super efficient `searchsorted`. Not surprised at all with the flying, NumPy in most occasions does ;)

Answer (score 0):

In the lack of better ideas, let me throw in a Pandas one-liner. Disclaimer: it works 100 times slower than Divakar's pure Numpy solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
pd.concat([df.set_index(ix)[0] for ix in [1,2]], axis=1).reset_index().values
#array([[  1.,   0.,   2.],
#       [  2.,   2.,   0.],
#       [  3.,  nan,   1.],
#       [  4.,   1.,  nan]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I am actually using Pandas here and having 10MB+ data, I appreciate these two orders of magnitude speed-up. ;)